# Change options menu icon within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I hava a little issue here. I have an application which have an option menu. For each fragment I display, I change the icon of this option menu (from a slider menu).

I need to change the icon from an intent (home fragment to another fragment). I want to change this option menu icon when the new fragment appears. I hope I made myself clear enough.

Comment: well fragments dont have intents so you cant do that

Comment: by intent I mean FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: ok but thats not an intent, anyway this should be handled by your activity

Comment: can you post you activity code ?